# How to change a CSS property with logical operator with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

An element with the class ".has_padding" needs to be set to "display:none;" **if it has no text content.** The other elements with the class ".has_padding" must still be visible if they do have a text inside.

In the following code I styled the elements a bit, so that you can easily understand my issue. (I want to get rid of the visible #DDD-colored padding, if the element is empty.)

NOTE: JQuery is added, so that you can run it without big effort.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
    .myBox {
        border: 2px solid #BBB;
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
    .has_padding {
        padding: 10px 40px;
        background: #DDD;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="myBox">
    <div class="has_padding"></div>
</div>

<div class="myBox">
    <div class="has_padding">I have text.</div>
</div>

<div class="myBox">
    <div class="has_padding">I have text too.</div>
</div>

<script>
    // your code here.
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are tight, I could not find an alike question before, I will now delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a :empty selector.

Use function like this...

```
$('div.has_padding:empty').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:empty` selector.

```js
$('.has_padding:empty').parent().hide();
```

```css
.myBox {
  border: 2px solid #BBB;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.has_padding {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  background: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myBox">
  <div class="has_padding"></div>
</div>

<div class="myBox">
  <div class="has_padding">I have text.</div>
</div>

<div class="myBox">
  <div class="has_padding">I have text too.</div>
</div>
```